# scalafx in scala project intellij (unresolved dependencies path:)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scalafx

i was compiling my scalafx code in intellij in a sbt file and they kept showing me this error, please help i tried everything but its still not working

```
[info] Updating
[info] Resolved  dependencies
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last update for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scalafx:scalafx_2.13:8.0.192-R14
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/xxxxx/.ivy2/local/org.scalafx/scalafx_2.13/8.0.192-R14/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalafx/scalafx_2.13/8.0.192-R14/scalafx_2.13-8.0.192-R14.pom
```

**this is my built.sbt**

```scala
name := "practical4b"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalafx/scalafx
libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx"%%"scalafx"%"8.0.192-R14"
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that there is no release of *ScalaFX* 8/R14 that works with *Scala* 2.13.

Each *Scala* release, with the exception of bug-fix releases, has different binary compatibility requirements. So if you're using a *Scala*-built library with, say, *Scala* 2.13, you need the build of that library created for the same *Scala* version. Libraries created from *Java* code typically have binary compatibility with any version of *Scala*.

To determine which *Scala* versions are supported, they are listed in the column under *Scala* on *Maven Central* (the site linked to in your code above the `libraryDependencies` property):
[image]

You can resolve this problem either by switching to *Scala* 2.12, by changing the *Scala* version as follows:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.12"
```

Or, you can use a more recent version of *ScalaFX*, that will work with *Scala* 2.13, by changing the library dependency as follows:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "12.0.2-R18"
```

to use R18, or:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "14-R19"
```

for R19.

A lot will depend upon which version of *Java* you are using. If you need to use *Scala* 2.13, with one of the more recent *ScalaFX* releases, I would recommend using *Java* 11 LTS. If you must use *Java* 8, then stay with the *ScalaFX* 8/R14 release and use *Scala* 2.12. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: hello i am using the latest java 8 JDK and also scalaVersion : 2.12.11 and also `libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "8.0.192-R14"`

i am receiving this error now instead

Symbol 'type javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle' is missing from the classpath.

[error] This symbol is required by 'class scalafx.scene.shape.Rectangle'.

[error] Make sure that type Rectangle is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.

[error] A full rebuild may help if 'Rectangle.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of javafx.scene.shape.

Comment: Which release of _Java_ are you using, and does it have _JavaFX_ installed with it? (_Oracle_'s official Java 8 JRE/JDK _does_ come with _JavaFX_, but most of the _OpenJDK_ releases _don't_ provide _JavaFX_. If you upgrade to _Java 11_ (any flavor), you can guarantee that _JavaFX_ isn't installed, but _ScalaFX_'s dependencies will download it from _Maven Central_.)

Comment: @lamecoder Did you see my comment in reply? Did that work for you or do you have any further questions. Let me know...

Comment: hello i am using the latest java 8 which is javac 1.8.0_261 and also sbt 2.12.11 ! i have found a solution to it and it works fine for now......

Comment: `lazy val osName = System.getProperty("os.name") match {`
 ` case n if n.startsWith("Linux") => "linux"`
 ` case n if n.startsWith("Mac") => "mac"`
`  case n if n.startsWith("Windows") => "win"`
  `case _ => throw new Exception("Unknown platform!")`
`}`

`// Add JavaFX dependencies`
`lazy val javaFXModules = Seq("base", "controls", "fxml", "graphics", "media", `"swing", `"web")`
`libraryDependencies ++= javaFXModules.map( m=>`
`  "org.openjfx" % s"javafx-$m" % "11" classifier osName`
`)`

Comment: thanks for your help! im new to this platform so its surprising for someone to help out